# Запуск python-скрипта из другого приложения

Tags: c++, python, qt

Запускаю скрипт так:

```
QProcess proс;
proc.setProgram("cam\\python-3.5.2\\python.exe");
proc.setArguments(QStringList() << "cam\\Program\\rotronic-rcvr\\json.py");
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
proc.setProcessEnvironment(env);
proc.setStandardErrorFile("error.log");
proc.setStandardOutputFile("output.log");
proc.setWorkingDirectory("cam\\python-3.5.2");
proc.start();
proc.waitForStarted(1000);
```

После запуска python сразу аварийно завершается. В стандартный поток ошибок выводит следующее:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00004ed8 (most recent call first):

При этом если запускать скрипт из командной строки, например, так:

> cam\python-3.5.2\python.exe cam\Program\rotronic-rcvr\json.py

то он запускается без проблем. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: не используйте имена модулей, которые конфликтуют со стандартной библиотекой--переименуйте `json.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решилось так. В список `env` каким-то образом попала переменная PYTHONHOME, в которой был прописан какой-то левый путь. После её удаления всё заработало.

Comment: Выберите этот ответ как верный

Answer (score 1):

Может PYTHONPATH не выставлен? Проверьте эту переменную в глобальном окружении.

`encodings` - это один из стандартных модулей python, может из-за отсутствия путей в PATH он и не может найти его

Есть баг на эту тему http://bugs.python.org/issue11288

upd

Я к сожалению не знаю c++, но мне со стороны подсказывают решение вида

```
Py_SetPythonHome(L"C:\\Path\\To\\My\\Python\\Installation")
```

Comment: Обсуждение по ссылке предлагает решение с точностью до наоборот: нужно почистить `%PYTHONPATH%` переменную окружения, чтобы она не содержала пути от Питона 2 (эта переменная окружения пустая при нормальной работе).

Comment: Завтра проверю.

Comment: @jfs я не очень хорошо знаю особенности работы python на windows, но наслышан, что для нормальной работы ему необходимо прописаться в PATH. По ссылке действительно был конфликт версий, что там у автора - остаётся только гадать

Comment: 1- PATH и PYTHONPATH это разные вещи. 2- здесь с++ запускает python как *внешний* процесс (аналог: `subprocess.call([sys.executable, r'..\json.py'], stdout=open('output.log'), stderr=open('error.log'), cwd=os.path.dirname(sys.executable), timeout=1)`), а  `Py_SetPythonHome()` вызов имеет смысл только если *внутри* процесса пытаться интерпретатор Питона запустить (embed), хотя стоит проверить что PYTHONHOME переменная окружения не установлена.

Comment: @jfs странно тогда. Я не учёл, что не из данной программы python выполняется нормально. Но мне всё-таки кажется, что как-то изменяется окружение. Вероятнее всего это какие-то тонкости работы QProcessEnvironment, мне это неизвестно. Удалю свой ответ, если не поможет